# Wrong configuration for Spring Security configured with Java Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Good morning.

I have an application built on Spring MVC and secured by Spring Security, in particular I am using these versions:

- Spring Security: 5.3.1.RELEASE;
- Spring MVC: 5.2.5.RELEASE.

**Main problem**

After setting up the application with Java based configuration (annotations) I was testing if login requests were handled properly, but I can't figure out why all requests are always redirected to the login page itself as in a kind of loop.

it's the first time I use Spring security to secure a web application and I didn't manage to find any answer yet.

**What have I done**

MVC part is working well without authentication (even the JDBC connection), the problem might be in the configuration of Spring security: in particular, security is based on JDBC authentication (Mysql is used as Database) and configuration is written with java based annotation.

I was testing wrongly typed username and password, so, as I saw in tutorials used, I should have been redirected to access denied page after typing wrong credentials, instead I am redirected again to login page.

I am not sure about this, but I think the main problem is in the method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            //configure security for pages
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('admin')")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            //creates login form
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/accessDenied")
            .usernameParameter("id_utente").passwordParameter("password")
            //catches exceptions http 403 response
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
}
```

which may not be configured correctly, I configured it in a way that:

- The custom form login (process by `.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")`) is displayed even for the homepage;
- If a user types credentials correctly, he is redirected to the homepage (`.defaultSuccessUrl("/home")`);
- otherwise he is redirected to the accessDenied page (`.failureUrl("/accessDenied")`).

After looking in Spring security documentation or on the internet I didn't found any similar problem and a solution to this issue, nor an extensive guide to configure security layer.

Below I provide the code written in order to let you see the configuration as a whole, thanks to all in advance.

Content of POM.xml:

```
<!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security-web}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security-config}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security-core}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security-taglibs}</version>
</dependency>
```

Content of SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("securityUserDetailService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /**
     * Manages the encoder to save passwords in the DB
     * not in plain text
     *
     * @return PasswordEncoder object
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Manages the configuration of the Authentication manager with
     * user credentials and roles.
     * <p>
     * The AuthenticationManager processes any authentication request.
     *
     * @param auth AuthenticationManagerBuilder object
     * @throws Exception exception
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Manages the configuration for specific http request.
     *
     * @param http HttpSecurity request
     * @throws Exception exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                //configure security for pages
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('admin')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                //creates login form
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/accessDenied")
                .usernameParameter("id_utente").passwordParameter("password")
                //catches exceptions http 403 response
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
    }

    /**
     * Manages the storage of user credentials inside database
     *
     * @return The authenticationProvider Object
     */
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider()
    {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver()
    {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }
}
```

Content of controller which manages urls involved:

```
@Autowired
AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;

/**
 * This method handles Access-Denied redirect.
 */
@GetMapping(value = "/accessDenied")
public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
    return "accessDenied";
}

/**
 * Handles login method.
 * If user is not logged, login page is returned,
 * root page otherwise.
 * @return view name
 */
@GetMapping(value = "/login")
public String loginPage() {
    if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
        return "login";
    } else {
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}

/**
 * If user is already authenticated returns true,
 * false otherwise.
 *
 * @return true is user is authenticated, false otherwise
 */
private boolean isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous() {
    final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication);
}
```

Content of login.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Login</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />

        <div class="leftBar">
            <h2>Login</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="rightBar">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                <form:form method="post" action="${loginUrl}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userId">ID utente</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userId" placeholder="ID utente">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="userPwd">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPwd" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn">Accedi</button>
                </form:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Content of userService injected into Spring security for authentication:

```
@Service("securityUserDetailService")
public class SecurityUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    UtentiService utentiService;

    /**
     * Manages the load of a user along with
     * ID and password.
     *
     * @param s user id
     * @return UserDetail object with ID and password
     * @throws UsernameNotFoundException If user is not found in the system
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(s);

        Utenti user = utentiService.findUserById(id);
        if(user == null)
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with id " + s + " not found");
        }

        return new User(Integer.toString(user.getId_utente()), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
    }

    /**
     * Determines which roles a particular user has
     *
     * @param user The user for which to find roles
     * @return List containing all roles related to the user
     */
    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Utenti user)
    {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getQualifica()));

        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Content of SecurityInitializer class (as shown in some tutorials), i would be grateful to the one who can explain me why this class has to be empty:

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{

}
```

Comment: Try setting `.antMatchers("/accessDenied").permitAll()`. The application may be redirecting to "/accessDenied", but then back to login because "/accessDenied" is secured.

Comment: that's actually the solution, I thought it was already implied in
.failureUrl("/accessDenied")
but it wasn't.